# Passing 2 value from 2 dropdown into 3rd dropdown

Tags: php, ajax

I have tried passing value on 3rd drop down but it doenst receive any of it 
it doesnt show error but it doesnt get any data from 2 dropdowns Im new to just and im trying something but it doesnt work at all pls help thank you very much 
dropdown.php

```
<select class="form-control" style="font-size: 21px;" name="Building" id="Building" onChange="change_floor(this.value)">
          <option>Select</option>
               <?php
              $res=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from Building");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                ?>
    <option  value="<?php echo $row['Building']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Building'];?></option>
              <?php
                 }
                ?>
               </select>

     <select class="form-control" style="font-size: 21px;" name="floor" id="Floor" onChange="change_floor(this.value)">
         <option>Select</option>
       <?php
      $res=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from floor");
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
         ?>
      <option  value="<?php echo $row['Floor']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Floor'];?></option>
         <?php
           }
         ?>
      </select>
            <div id="Dept"></div>
              </div>

</div>
      <script type="text/javascript ">
              function change_floor(str,str1) {

if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("Dept").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("Dept").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "deptajax.php?q="+str+"&d="+str1, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
 }


  </script>
```

deptajax.php
If I use request here i shows error but if I use GET i doesnt show any error what is more usable for this scenario?

```
      <?php
      $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","id5592115_retep","Password");
      mysqli_select_db($link,"id5592115_admin");

      $q = $_REQUEST["q"];
      $d = $_REQUEST["d"];

$res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from depttable where Flr='$d' and 
    Building='$q' order by deptname asc");
echo "<form method='get' action='table2.php'>";
echo '
<select class="form-control" style="font-size: 21px;" name="dept">
';
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
$deptid = $row['deptid'];
$deptname = $row['deptname'];
echo "<option value='".$deptname."'>".$deptname."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-light 
    btnmove">Submit</button>';
echo "</form>";
    ?>
```

Comment: You javascript function is expecting 2 parameters str and str1 but you are only passing one from each select. I bet it is throwing exception in your browser console. Validate the values before passing them to ajax. Test the flow step by step to see where and why it is failing.

Comment: what do you mean I have 2 dropdowns? but yeah it only gets 1 data -

Comment: @NawedKhan i tried echoing  and yeah they only get 1 data when i use either of the 2 dropdown and the  other variable is undentified

Comment: @NawedKhan what do you mean that it on passing one from each select 
it shouldnt be  1 dropdown =  1  variable?

Comment: @NawedKhan sir what do you mean about expecting 2 parameters str and str1 but you are only passing one from each select.  sorry im not quite familiar

Comment: The function "change_floor(str, str1)" is expecting 2 parameters str and str1. But onchange of each dropdown you are only passing the selected value of THAT dropdown: change_floor(this.value). This means everytime the function is called by either dropdown only str is passed and str1 will always be undefined. The whole logic is flawed. Lastly... the ajax is returning a select with only one option and a submit button? why do you even need a third dropdown if it always have only one value?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onclick` function is call every time you `select` any of the dropdown , so at a time only one value is passed i.e : either `str`  or `str1` will have value . Instead to avoid this you can do like below :

When first `selectbox` is selected try to `store` it value in some variable like below :

```
    <select class="form-control" style="font-size: 21px;" name="floor" id="Floor" 
onChange="change_floor1(this.value)">
                 <!--^ make another function  with name change_floor1-->
             <option>Select</option>
          ...
          </select>
```

Then in your `<script></script>`do like below :

```
 var s; // declare globally 
 function change_floor1(str) {
   s=str; //assigning value of first-select box in "s"
  }
  function change_floor(str1) {

if (str1.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("Dept").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("Dept").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
   //passing both value 
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "deptajax.php?q="+s+"&d="+str1, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
 }
```